# shared queue between multiple process in perl

Tags: perl, fork, expect

The following senario was done using threads

1. A large queue `@work_queue` populated/enqueued by the main thread. Used `Thread::Queue` here.
2. ≥ 2 connection objects of something are added in `@conns` which had to be loaded serially as part of the loading process uses `Expect->spawn`
3. Multiple Worker threads are invoked, and each thread given a single `$conns[$i]` object & reference to the shared `\@work_queue`.
4. The worker threads safely removes a single item from `@work_queue` and performs some processing through its connection object, after which it picks up the next available item from `@work_queue`.
5. When this `@work_queue` is empty all the threads will shutdown safely

Now, the problem is that the loading phase is taking too long in many cases. But due to the use of `Expect->spawn`, parallel loading of `@conns` is possible only on a separate process & not on a thread.

Please suggest a good way to achieve the above scenario using fork. Or, even better if there is a way to use `Expect->spawn` with threads. (UNIX/LINUX only)

See [Is it possible to use threads with Expect?](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod#Is_it_possible_to_use_threads_with_Expect?)

Comment: Change `use threads` to `use forks` (install from CPAN) and your script should work without further changes. While memory usage should go down, accessing shared data is more expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I will install some of these required libraries and try t out.